# Can same function be called with different header files?

Tags: c++

I have a function:

--- showme.cpp

```
void showme () {
   std::cout <<"I am " << T << endl;
}
```

`T is a parameter that should come with a #define`

-- top.cpp

```
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  // I want to call showme() with different "T" values defined by #define

  #define T 5
  showme();

  #define T 6
  showme();

}
```

I am not sure if there is a better/efficient way to do it.

Comment: Why aren't you using a function parameter?

Comment: Use function parameters? Why do you want to use `#define` for this? Or at all

Comment: Macros do simply text substitution in the same file. Defining a macro in `top.cpp` has no effect on `showme.cpp`.

Comment: First and foremost, it won't work - macro `T` in translation unit `showme.cpp` will not be affected anyway by macro `T` in translation unit `top.cpp`.

Comment: This is a nice example of XY problem. What are you actually trying to do? There are several possible solutions to several possible problems.

Comment: I am making this C++ code for High-Level Synthesis. Which does not allow for dynamic memory allocation. If I use T as my array index it throws an error. The only way I can use T is through a #define

Comment: Make it a template parameter.

Comment: Yup, SergeyA was right on the money. Classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You did something, got an error, and instead of asking about *that*, you ask about an impossible "solution".

Answer (score 3):

Based on the explanation in the comments what you really want is to have a `template` function, so your example should be changed to:

```
#include <iostream>

template<size_t T> //or int or whatever other type you really need to use
void showme () {
   std::cout << "I am " << T << std::endl;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  showme<5>();

  showme<6>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the function to take a parameter. You can use the macro when calling the function.

```
void showme (int T) {
   std::cout <<"I am " << T << endl;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  // I want to call showme() with different "T" values defined by #define

  #define T 5
  showme(T);

  #define T 6
  showme(T);

}
```